# OUT is always empty in command line but not in SQL client?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I am trying to execute a Stored Routine in MySQL and when I run that in HeidiSQL it runs just fine, returning a message as it's supposed to, but when I run it using NodeJS the return message is always empty.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '',
    user: '',
    password: '',
    database: '',
    multipleStatements: true
});

con.connect(function(err) {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("Connection Established!");
});

var AddPointsDiscord =
"CALL AddPointsDiscord(?,?,@RETURN_MESSAGE);"+
"SELECT @RETURN_MESSAGE;";

var user = '';
var ScoreAdded = 1;
var ReturnMessage = '';

con.query(AddPointsDiscord, [user, ScoreAdded, ReturnMessage], function(err, result) {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log(ReturnMessage);
});
```

The Parameters are:

- USER - A Varchar for a Discord ID (IN)
- ADD_SCORE - The new score to add to the user (IN)
- RETURN_MESSAGE - The message that's supposed to be returned (OUT)

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you run into async behavior here: Your function is finished before the result of the query has been returned by the database.

To catch the async behavior, use the callback functionalities:

```
con.query(AddPointsDiscord, [user, ScoreAdded, ReturnMessage], function(err, result) {
    if (err) 
        callback(err,null);
    else
        callback(null,ReturnMessage);
});
```

Comment: Is `callback` a function? It's unknown by nodejs.

Comment: No, you would have to implement that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24232350/node-mysql-async-multiple-queries is a nice in depth one. If it works, I will mark your post as possible duplicate and remove this answer.

Comment: I've tried to follow the example, but it still doesn't work :/. This is what I got `var callback = function(obj,msg) { 
    if(obj !== null) {
        throw obj;
    } else {
        console.log(msg);
    }
};` and this is what I did to my query: `con.query(AddPointsDiscord, [user, ScoreAdded, ReturnMessage], function(err, result) {
    if (err) 
        callback(err,null);
    else
        callback(null,ReturnMessage);
});`