# Mysql, saving query result

Tags: node.js

In all tutorials I searched the web, they print the rows/result using `console.log` the from the mysql query. In my case, I want to store that value to manipulate it in a function. The problem is that node doesn't wait. Can you help me in catching the rows in such example? How can I store the rows in a variable?

```
con.connect(function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  con.query("SELECT * FROM customers", function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
  });
});
```

I tested one of the solutions but I got [] when trying to get result/rows out of the function. I want to use the result in the `savedServices: []`  see below:
[image]

Comment: Use `async` module

Comment: i know it, but how to apply it, please make an answer to mark it.

Comment: Express not waiting doesn't have anything to do with express. It's related to node. Wrap this in a function and callback with results, then do whatever you need with the result, store it in a variable or whatnot.

Comment: Also, stop throwing errors and call back with the errors instead. If you don't, you'll have problems handling errors in your application.

Comment: @Diamond Let me know if you want me to write an example.

Comment: thank your for reply. I already wrapped it in a function, I got it undefined. But let us see your example, I will appreciate that and mark it as an answer. thank you

Comment: any update? waiting for the example. appreciate you for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a fresh start with a simple project

> Follow below commands

```
mkdir testdb
cd testdb
npm install --save mysql
npm install --save async
```

> Create a test.js file

```
vim text.js
```

> Now put below code in the test.js file

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var async = require('async');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  database: "mydb",
  user: "user",
  password: "pass"
});

var myrows = [];

async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
        con.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("Connected!");
        var sql = 'select * from users limit 5';
        con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
          if (err) throw err;

          result.forEach(function(item) {
            //console.log(item);
            myrows.push(item);
          });
          callback(null, myrows);
        });
      });
    }
],
// optional callback
function(err, myrows) {
    console.log("myrows:::");
    console.log(myrows);
});
```

now test the file

```
node test.js
```

> You should see results like this:

```
Connected!
Result: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I appreciate that, but you didn't  store the results/rows in a variable, which I state clearly in the post!

Comment: thank you for interaction. I wanted to show the result to you on a screenshot, so I updated the post with an screenshot. please check it and let us keep going on it to solve it. thank you.

Comment: it is async issue.

Comment: Yes in this case you will need to use async. Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/30973427/1225070

Comment: i am tired of applying that and couldn't achieve it, if that easy for you, please update your answer with the fix. I want to see how applied. I want to mark your answer as best answer.

Comment: Happy to help you brother

Comment: I am excited about you that you are really approaching to get it done. Please take a look at the screenshot updated on the post. You will see the result, and understand what little things needed to reach what I aim to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166737/discussion-between-elegant-user-and-diamond).